# Whatsapp cloud API for a partner managed account

Tags: whatsapp, zoho, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have a whatsapp number connected to zoho desk (using for omni-channel support), the payment method is automatically set to ZOHO CORPORATION PRIVATE LIMITED.

I want to send other notifications (authentication, marketing, etc) using the same number, but I am not able to figure out how to do so.

Can I generate auth token for a whatsapp number managed by some other service?

Currently I cannot see the phone number I am using with the partner listed in "API Setup" section of meta developers.

Thanks in advance

Previosuly, I was using Chatwoot, the billing was managed by organisation, and I was able to use it with chatwoot and with tokens separately as well

Comment: More often than not, companies that do not provide APIs, but only give end interfaces to their customers - do not provide API Key to their users. In theory, this is not correct, and the user should have full access to the management of his number.
If the number is registered specifically to your business, you have the right to move it to another BSP for example. It's strange that you don't see your number in the meta developers section. Does it belong to you?

Comment: I agree, I see the number of developer's page, not just in the API setup section. Checked with the Zoho team - they are managing the keys and the billing, and cannot sharet the keys. Neither do they have their APIs which allow me to send messages

Comment: Then you can run the migration process yourself to ISVs that share keys